# Trigger validation after first submit, then after after every keystroke on input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation for everything I'm about to talk below.

so I have an input field, lets call it email.  I also have a submit button for this form.  Now by default the error message for email field will not kick in until I hit the submit button.  Then whenever I type it will show/hide error message dependant on if it is a valid email.  This check happens with every key stroke and this is a very important distinction to make so that you would understand my problem I posted below.

Now I have a background colour on the input, it is suppose to be green when validation has passed and red when it has failed.  I have this part working, let me show you how I did it:

```
window.onload = function () {
    $(".js-validate-circle").on("input", function () {
        UpdateValidationCircle(this);
    });
}
function UpdateValidationCircle(e) {
    if ($(e).valid()) {
        $(e).parent().addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(e).parent().removeClass("active");
    }
}
```

The `active` class is what determines if its green or red.  There is styling that is irrelevant I think to the question so I wont post it here.

Here is my problem: When the page loads and I start typing, it forces validation to trigger and error messages start coming in before I click the submit button for the first time.  I am trying to prevent this.  I want the color the start changing on typing only after the submit button was hit.  Functionality of my red/green background should match jquery validation messages.

How would I accomplish something like this?  I tried using on change but then the validation triggers only when the box loses focus.

Comment: Are you talking about the jQuery Validate plugin?  If so, where is the rest of the code?  The call to `.validate()`?  The HTML markup?

Comment: @Sparky HTML markup is pointless for this problem so I didn't post it, and I am not calling .validate() anywhere in my code.  This is a pure jquery/javascript question.  .valid() calls .validate(), from my research online, it is not how this is documented, but it is how it behaves.  For this reason my validation kicks in on the first key stroke.  If valid() did not call validate then I would have this behaving exactly how I want it.

Comment: You cannot use `.valid()` without first calling `.validate()` and you can't use either method without including the jQuery Validate plugin,.  See:  [*"`.validate()` needs to be called on the form before checking it using this method"*](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

// Cache elements
var $circle = $(".js-validate-circle");
var addedInputEvent = false; // Just a flag to know if we already added the evt listener

// On form submit....
$("#form").on("submit", function(event) {

   // Prevent default form submit
   event.preventDefault();

   // Check immediately
   $circle.each(UpdateValidationCircle);

   // If not already assigned, assign an "input" listener
   if(!addedInputEvent) {
       addedInputEvent = true;
       $circle.on("input",  UpdateValidationCircle);
   }
});

function UpdateValidationCircle() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.parent().toggleClass("active", $el.valid());
}

});
```

Comment: What you wrote above will cause my background to change only after I the submit button.  This is true only for the first hit, then after that it should check after every key stroke.

Comment: Now that I think more about it, all I really need is a check that says, was submit button pressed once?

Comment: **Edited** to account for the "allow input event after first submit try" @Bagzli

Comment: I see that you are making updates to clean up the code, I appreciate that and I like what you did, I got one question though.  Shouldn't `$circle.each` be `$(circle).each`?  I am asking cause I'm getting complaints from resharper.

Comment: @Bagzli `var $circle = $(".js-validate-circle");` see? it's already wrapped in jQuery. No need to re-wrap a jquery object again into jQuery.

Comment: I did, but resharper still complains, that is why I'm asking.

Comment: @Bagzli if it complaints about valid code... find a better tool (never heard about `resharper`) ... perhaps remove the leading `$` from the variable name. - So instead of `$circle` use `circle`

Comment: @Bagzli try wrapping your code in `DOM ready` like I did. That way I'm moving the `$` alias into an inner scope.

Comment: removing the $ and using the variable as is seems to work, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Use the `keyup` event instead:

```
$(".js-validate-circle").on("keyup", function () {
...
```

Assuming `.js-validate-circle` is your input... or if it is the form:

```
$(".js-validate-circle").on("keyup", "#id-of-the-input", function () {
...
```

If this doesn't work, we are going to need to see `validate()`s code and some markup.

Comment: The Q title says **`Trigger validation only after submit`** yet you suggested to use `keyup` over the preferred (and already in use) `"input"` event.

Comment: But in the description he says `whenever I type it will show/hide error message dependant on if it is a valid email`.